# Cool little system of equations.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Solving the system of equations for integers:

$2^a+3^b=5^b$

$3^a+6^b=9^b$

How is it done? I tried substituting the $2^a$ from the first equation into the second, and dividing the two equations by $2^a$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second equation gives you $b\le a\lt2b$, because $3^b+6^b\le9^b\lt3^{2b}+6^b$ when $b\gt0$ (and the equations obviously have no solutions when $b\le0$).

By diving it by $3^b$, you get $3^{a-b}+2^b=3^b$.

It means $2^b=3^b-3^{a-b}=3^{a-b}(3^{2b-a}-1)$.

By unicity of decomposition in prime factors, we must have $a-b=0$, so $a=b$, and $2^b=3^b-1$.

This is only possible if $a=b=1$. Then the two equations are verified. Notice that the first one is not needed to find the necessary condition $a=b=1$.

Comment: a>b only holds if you assume them to be positive integers. Even for $a=b=0$ your inequality is false.

Comment: yes but this is easy to rule out this case from the original equations.

Comment: Denis, I hope you don't mind the minor edit I made.  I think it addresses flawr's comment.

Comment: Cool, but what if somehow $3^{2b-a}-1$  cancels out the $3^{a-b}$ and $3^{a-b}$ becomes $2^x$?

Comment: @JackiePoehler We know that $b>a-b$, because $2^b=3^b-3^{a-b}$.So $2b-a>0$, and both factors are integers.

Comment: Denis, I made a second edit that I think answers Jackie Poehler's comment as well.

Comment: cool, this is very neat and clear now

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by inspection, where $a=1$ and $b=1$.

Comment: And how did you prove that this were the only solutions?